# Is there a way to get the stack trace from the web version of React Native(expo)?

Tags: react-native, error-handling, expo, stack-trace

I have an app in react native Expo, am running it on web, and want to be able to get the stacktrace for what line in the original react native code an error occurs from. Is this possible?